# nvd3 line chart automatically setting fill opacity

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I'm trying to create a line chart using nvd3 using the following code

```
nv.addGraph(function ()
{
    chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
        .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
        .showXAxis(true)
        .showYAxis(true)
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true);
    chart.xAxis     //Chart x-axis settings
        .axisLabel('Time (ms)')
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            var format = '%H:%M';
            d = new Date(d);
            return d3.time.format(format)(d);
        }).tickValues(null);


    d3.select('#macCountGraph svg')
        .datum(graphData)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});
```

The above code is creating the graph as required but it is filling the graph as shown in the image below

[image]

Also, it not showing the grid lines, x-axis, y-axis and no tooltip is shown onmouseover.

I looked inside the generated svg and found this

```
<g class=" nv-group nv-series-0" style="stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1.5; fill: rgb(31, 119, 180); stroke: rgb(31, 119, 180); fill-opacity: 0.5;">
```

The above element has a fill-opacity set to 0.5. If I change it to 0 in firebug, the fill color is removed.

Tried to do it using javascript as shown below

```
d3.selectAll("svg .nv-groups > nv-group")
  .transition()
  .style("fill-opacity", 0);
```

But no luck.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Nobody answered this part of the question, which I have as well: "Also, it not showing the grid lines, x-axis, y-axis and no tooltip is shown onmouseover."

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on `d3 3.5.5` with `nvd3 1.8.1`. Setting `area` in the data *does* work, in that it sets the chart area, but separately of the problem described here (for example, if you set `area: "red"`, you will end up with *two* filled regions).

Fix by setting the style of the `.nv-line` class element. In your case, try this:

```
d3.selectAll("svg .nv-line")
  .style("fill", "none"); // or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.

1. Add you `area: false` in the data, you pass into the chart

   ```
   var data = [{
       values: [],
       key: 'Time',
       color: '#7777ff',
       area: false //area - set to true if you want the area filled into the line chart.
   }];
   ```
2. Or you can use the following code. To test it, open the debugger toolbar paste the code on the page console [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html). I've tested it and it works.

   ```
   d3.select("svg g.nv-series-2").style("fill-opacity", 0);
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had tried setting area: false.... but that didn't work, I got some weird output which was highly undesired. Just tired using your second option... but that is also yielding the desired result...

Comment: Can you put your code in JSFiddle with the data, so someone can have a look.

Comment: The `area` option controls fill under the line, not the kind of 'shape fill' OP is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parameters for y-axis and x-axis to show the lines :

```css
.nvd3 .nv-axis path.domain {
    stroke-opacity: .75;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis.nv-x path.domain {
    stroke-opacity: .75;
}
```